# How to change or remove the bibliography title when using multibib?

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, naming, multibib

I use the [`multibib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multibib) package to include more than one bibliography into my document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{lit}{Literature}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystylelit{alpha}
\bibliographylit{Literatur.bib}                  
\nocitelit{*}

\end{document}
```

I want to include the references with `\nocite` but without the title "Literature". Normally I can change the title with `\renewcommand{\refname}{New Title}` (assuming the `article` class), but this is not working with `multibib`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or select your code and hit Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the second argument of `\newcites` to change the bibliography title. EDIT: To completely remove the bibliography heading, change the (class-dependend) definition of `\thebibliography` (this also works without `multibib`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{lit}{New Title}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{%
  \section*{\refname}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocitelit{*}
\bibliographystylelit{alpha}
\bibliographylit{mybib}                  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After struggling for three days, I found a very simple solution to remove the title regardless of the file class or any other package being used simultaneously: rather than leaving the title argument empty, you need to use the {} as the argument for each new citation:

in short: \newcites{main,method}{{},{}}

```
\documentclass{extarticle} 
%any other class should work, i have tried IEEEtran and article and it did work just %fine
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{main,method}{{},{}} 

% here rather than leaving the argument as empty use  empty curly brackets

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\citemain{entry1}
%assuming there exist references with the key named "entry1" and "entry2"  in the bib file
\bibliographystylemain{plain}
\bibliographymain{refs} 
 %assuming there is a bib file with the name "refs"
\blindtext
\citemethod{entry2}
\bibliographystylemethod{plain}
\bibliographymethod{refs}  
\end{document}
```

assuming the name of the .tex file is "document", run

pdflatex document

bibtex main.aux

bibtex method.aux

pdflatex document

pdflatex document

Comment: This is fantastic. So simple and works like a charm. I was looking at much more complex answers.